# How to extract the characters from a string in Excel

Tags: excel

Hi I would like to extract dynamically the numbers from string in Excel.

I have the following strings and I would like to have only the numbers before ". pdf". taken out of the string into the next column.

As you can see the number of characters varies from line to line.

I have invented something like this:

```
=MID(M20;SEARCH("_";M20);20)
```

But this takes out only the numbers after "_" and .pdf after this....

How to make it the way I like?

```
D:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\1610\ts25b_4462.pdf    
D:\Users\xxx\Desktop\1610\ts02b_39522.pdf
D:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\1610\ts02b_except_39511.pdf
D:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\1610\ts02b_except_39555.pdf    
D:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\1610\ts22b_6118.pdf
```

So that I have just :

```
4462    
39522    
39511    
39555    
6118     
and so on...
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

With this formula, you should be able to get the numbers you want:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))))+1,FIND(".",A1)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))))-1)
```

Basically, this is the initial fomula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("_",A1)+1,FIND(".",A1)-FIND("_",A1)-1)
```

But since there may be two `_` in the string so this is the one to find the 2nd `_`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","")))
```

Now just replace this `SUBSTITUTE` with `A1` above and you get that long formula.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

With VBA, try to do it like this:

```
Public Function splitThings(strInput As String) As String

    splitThings = Split(Split(strInput, "_")(1), ".")(0)

End Function
```

Concerning your formula, try to use `=LEFT(MID(M20;SEARCH("_";M20);20),K)`, where K is the difference of the length of `ts22b_6118.pdf` and 4 `(.pdf)`. 4 is the length of `.pdf`.
Something like this should do the work:

```
=LEFT(MID(I3,SEARCH("_",I3)+1,LEN(I3)),LEN(MID(I3,SEARCH("_",I3),LEN(I3)))-5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it using Excel formula. For example:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".pdf",A1)-1),LEFT(A1,FIND("_",A1)),"")
```

Using the first line as an example, with `LEFT(A1,FIND(".pdf",A1)-1)` you will have D:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\1610\ts25b_4462 and with the `LEFT(A1,FIND("_",A1))` D:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\1610\ts25b_, if you SUBSTITUTE the first part by "" you will have 4462.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the number you want regardless of extension (could be .pdf, could be .xlsx, etc) and regardless of the number of underscores present in the filename and/or filepath:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(M20,".",REPT(" ",LEN(M20))),"_",REPT(" ",LEN(M20))),LEN(M20)*2),LEN(M20)))
```